# RESTful Client - Which URI and where to redirect?

Tags: php, rest, api

I'm new to REST and currently trying to develop a RESTful service (PHP).

Let's say I have a simple client (HTML/jQuery) with a button to show me all cars from a database. What I don't understand is which `href` do I put to the button on my client?

```
a) <a class="button" href="http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cars">Show all
cars</a>

b) <a class="button" href="http://localhost:3000/cars">Show all cars</a>
```

I assume users should not be able to see the direct API URI and therefor **b)** is the right way? 
If yes, that would mean I have to redirect the request within my backend server?

[Example drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch7bd.png)

I would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: a and b is same. and api request response json it not do any rendering of a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RESTful API would not do any rendering of a webpage. So sending the client to such an URL would be wrong.

You should use `AJAX` to make such call. Then you can also use the full potential of an API with `POST` and `PUT` calls.

Comment: Okay. So using a `$("button").click` function and point the `$getJSON` to _http://localhost:3000/api/v1/cars_ would be the right way?

Comment: Yes. You also might want to do something similar with your form submits - then using a `$.post()` of course.